# Delete Text by Position tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and tkinter and I have been looking for a solution to this issue for a while.

I am creating a sudoku board and filling in the known values using tkinter.  I want to go back and delete some of the numbers at known positions by I can't figure out how to do this using the delete function.

My board is build as follows:

```
for i in range(10)
    color = "blue" if i%3 ==0 else "gray"
    thickness = 5 if i% 3 ==0 else 1
    x0 = 10 + i* 5
    y0 = 10
    x1 = 10+ i * 5
    y1 = 500 - 10
    canvas.create_line(x0,y0,x1,y1, fill=color, width=thickness)

    x0 = 10
    y0 = 10 + i * 5
    x1 = 500 - 10
    y1 10 + i *5
    canvas.create_line(x0,y0,x1,y1, fill=color, width=thickness)
```

My function to add the numbers to the board is as follows:

```
def uploadBoard():
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            number = puzzleBoard[i][j]
            if number != 0:
                x = 10 + j * 5 + 5/2
                y = 10 + i * 5 + 5/2
                canvas.create_text(x,y, text=number)
```

The `puzzleBoard` is an array of arrays containing numbers.

What I want to do is create a function that will delete a number at a specific (i,j) location when the corresponding value in `puzzleBoard[i][j]` has been changed to 0.

Comment: iirc, `canvas.create_text` returns a reference to a canvas object which you can then use to interact with that object

Comment: @Nullman how do I know what the reference is?

Comment: read the [item specifiers](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#item-specifiers), they have some examples there as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an item on the canvas, the canvas returns an identifier. You can use this identifier later to modify or delete the item. You simply need to save this identifier.

Example:

First, save a reference when you create the items. Start by creating an empty dictionary, and then using the tuple `(i,j)` as the key:

```
item = {}
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
       ...
           item[(i,j)] = canvas.create_text(x,y, text=number)
```

Next, use the item id you've saved to delete the item:

```
canvas.delete(item[(i,j)])
```